# Mimic Power Line

Tags: power-supply, power, line

For a class I am making a system to remotely turn on and off a light as well as adjust the brightness through a dimmer(this one: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Trimatron-600-Watt-3-Way-Incandescent-Rotary-Dimmer-White-R62-06683-0IW/202077656).

For demonstration purposes I don't think it would make sense to actually wire this to the standard power line, so I was wondering if these components would still work if they were connected to a power supply or function generator instead.  If not, what would be the best way to demonstrate this system without basically installing it in the classroom?

For reference, this class is more about the code and embedded system I'm using to control this, but I think it would be important for my demonstration to actually show the product doing what it's supposed to.

All the best!

Comment: If you're plugging your function generator into the wall and then using that to generate 120VAC, then you're just creating a complicated middle man. Use a variac if you have one and just display your output waveform on an oscilloscope (or actually power a bulb if you want to draw the power from the wall)

Comment: The spec on the linked web page says voltage is 120 VAC.  It doesn't say what range the part will work over, so changing it may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would mount the dimmer and a lamp socket in standard electrical boxes.  I would cut the female end from a three-conductor extension cord, and use that to plug your demo device into a handy outlet.  For safety, connect the green ground wire in the cord to the metal boxes.